# How can I download a GIF from a URL In Swift (Gif From Tenor)

Tags: ios, swift, gif

I am running into two issues trying to download a Gif from Tenor. In my main app I pass in my API_Key and make a request which in return gives me a ITEMURL: https://tenor.com/view/yes-chuck-norris-approves-thumbs-up-gif-14366055 and a URL: https://tenor.com/8rqJ.gif

I am able to open the url on a browser and see the  gif but I cannot download it to the app. I have a ViewController that I will post below. I really am looking for a way to successfully download the gif from the tenor url. I was able to make the gif work with a public URL: https://blog.hootsuite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/How-to-Make-a-GIF-1.gif HERE IS MY CODE

**MY ViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import FLAnimatedImage

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let imageView = FLAnimatedImageView()
    let button = UIButton()
    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupButton()
        setupSpinner()
        setupImageView()
    }
    
    private func setupButton() {
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50)
        button.backgroundColor = .black
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getGif), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    private func setupSpinner() {
        view.addSubview(spinner)
        spinner.center = view.center
    }
    
    private func setupImageView() {
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 600, width: 200, height: 200)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.center = view.center
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }
    
    @objc func getGif() {
        // Create a URL for the GIF
        spinner.startAnimating()
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://blog.hootsuite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/How-to-Make-a-GIF-1.gif") else { return }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                print("Invalid Response")
                return
            }
            
            //make sure there is data
            guard let data = data else {
                print("No Data returned")
                return
            }
            
            let animatedImage = FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    this.spinner.stopAnimating()
                    this.button.isHidden = true
                    this.imageView.animatedImage = animatedImage
                }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I think it would be wise to mention I am using [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage) to help with showing the Gif. I am open to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem with the Tenor URL.

The reason I was not able to show it on the app is that I was showing the URL that is on Tenor's site which also has other GIFs on there as well. After looking over the response from the API I noticed it gives back a bunch of media formats. (I will paste the response below if anyone cares to see)

I noticed the gif media format and opened that in my browser and found out that this URL took me to ONLY this jif with no other content on the page. I rewrote my Struct model to match this and BOOM... problem solved.

**Data Model Struct:**

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Content
struct Content: Decodable {
    let results: [Result]
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Decodable {
    let media_formats: MediaFormats
}

// MARK: - MediaFormats
struct MediaFormats: Decodable {
    let gif: GIF
}

// MARK: - GIF
struct GIF: Decodable {
    let url: String
}
```

**Response From API call:**

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "7321207095287125549",
            "title": "texas",
            "media_formats": {
                "tinywebm": {
                    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/ZZonEFGoli0AAAP3/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger.webm",
                    "duration": 0,
                    "preview": "",
                    "dims": [
                        320,
                        240
                    ],
                    "size": 57989
                },
                "tinygifpreview": {
                    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/ZZonEFGoli0AAAAF/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger.png",
                    "duration": 0,
                    "preview": "",
                    "dims": [
                        220,
                        165
                    ],
                    "size": 0
                },
                "mp4": {
                    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/ZZonEFGoli0AAAPo/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger.mp4",
                    "duration": 2.3,
                    "preview": "",
                    "dims": [
                        400,
                        300
                    ],
                    "size": 139907
                },
                "webm": {
                    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/ZZonEFGoli0AAAPs/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger.webm",
                    "duration": 0,
                    "preview": "",
                    "dims": [
                        400,
                        300
                    ],
                    "size": 65667
                },
                "nanogifpreview": {
                    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/ZZonEFGoli0AAAAT/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger.png",
                    "duration": 0,
                    "preview": "",
                    "dims": [
                        120,
                        90
                    ],
                    "size": 0
                },
                "nanomp4": {
                    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/ZZonEFGoli0AAAP2/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger.mp4",
                    "duration": 2.3,
                    "preview": "",
                    "dims": [
                        150,
                        112
                    ],
                    "size": 45110
                },
                "tinygif": {
                    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/ZZonEFGoli0AAAAM/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger.gif",
                    "duration": 0,
                    "preview": "",
                    "dims": [
                        220,
                        165
                    ],
                    "size": 266545
                },
                "gifpreview": {
                    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/ZZonEFGoli0AAAAe/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger.png",
                    "duration": 0,
                    "preview": "",
                    "dims": [
                        400,
                        300
                    ],
                    "size": 37163
                },
                "nanogif": {
                    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/ZZonEFGoli0AAAAS/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger.gif",
                    "duration": 0,
                    "preview": "",
                    "dims": [
                        120,
                        90
                    ],
                    "size": 103784
                },
                "mediumgif": {
                    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/ZZonEFGoli0AAAAd/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger.gif",
                    "duration": 0,
                    "preview": "",
                    "dims": [
                        400,
                        300
                    ],
                    "size": 991245
                },
                "tinymp4": {
                    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/ZZonEFGoli0AAAP1/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger.mp4",
                    "duration": 2.3,
                    "preview": "",
                    "dims": [
                        320,
                        240
                    ],
                    "size": 127441
                },
                "loopedmp4": {
                    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/ZZonEFGoli0AAAPo/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger.mp4",
                    "duration": 2.3,
                    "preview": "",
                    "dims": [
                        400,
                        300
                    ],
                    "size": 139907
                },
                "gif": {
                    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/ZZonEFGoli0AAAAC/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger.gif",
                    "duration": 0,
                    "preview": "",
                    "dims": [
                        400,
                        300
                    ],
                    "size": 1520206
                },
                "nanowebm": {
                    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/ZZonEFGoli0AAAP4/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger.webm",
                    "duration": 0,
                    "preview": "",
                    "dims": [
                        150,
                        112
                    ],
                    "size": 56817
                }
            },
            "created": 1460746269.6868651,
            "content_description": "Texas GIF",
            "itemurl": "https://tenor.com/view/chuck-norris-walker-texas-ranger-gif-5336135",
            "url": "https://tenor.com/wykR.gif",
            "tags": [
                "Chuck Norris",
                "Walker Texas Ranger"
            ],
            "flags": [],
            "hasaudio": false
        }
    ],
    "next": "CAEQ79qe_OSJ_AIaHgoKAD-_xhumWuxY_xIQOpL78_1184rUPMB1AAAAADAy"
}
```